# Round cornered image/Profile Pic in Ionic 2/3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Im trying to show a round/circular image in profile component. I have tried following approaches.But nothing worked

1)

```
<ion-avatar>
<img  [src]=""  *ngIf=""/>
</ion-avatar>
```

2)

```
<img class="image"/>

css
.image {
    //its  working 
    margin: auto;
     height: 100px; 
     width: 100px; 
   // border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
    display: block;

     background-image: url('/assets/img/pixels.jpg');
}
```

Approach one  yielding  Squared  image  which is  enclosed below.
[image: Getting Square for first approach]

Please suggest  one  possible  solution. as  it  is  common scenario for  every ionic developer.

Comment: _nothing worked_.. you mean image didnt load? are you getting error?

Comment: Styling  is  not  accurate..

Comment: can you add some screenshot to show what you are getting?

Comment: with `border-radius: 50%` and `display: block` you will alway achive a round image. Must be have some css overide it. Try to add `!important`. Inspect your image and find out all css. Or create a live version of your project in plunker.  So we will easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprise to have been downvoted on my answer. Below is how I clearly got my answer. It perfectly worked for me.

> my profile.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

/*
  Generated class for the GeneralMyprofile page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-general-myprofile',
  templateUrl: 'general-myprofile.html'
})
export class GeneralMyprofilePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello GeneralMyprofilePage Page');
  }

}
```

> my profile.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="accent">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>My Profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="assets/img/marty-avatar.png" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Marty McFly</h2>
      <p>November 5, 1955</p>
    </ion-item>

    <img src="img/advance-card-bttf.png">

    <ion-card-content>
      <p>Wait a minute. Wait a minute, Doc. Uhhh... Are you telling me that you built a time machine... out of a DeLorean?!
        Whoa. This is heavy.</p>
    </ion-card-content>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
        <div>12 Likes</div>
      </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        <div>4 Comments</div>
      </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col center text-center>
        <ion-note>
          11h ago
        </ion-note>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-card>



</ion-content>
```

> Result --- My Raw Image has equal height and width at 88px X 88px

[image]

> Result of your own image With Raw Image at unequal height and width at 281px X 256px ( **so why it didn't work for you is that you have unequal height and width**)

[image]

**Now after I adjusted your raw image to equal height and width at 200px X 200px**

> The result

[image]

Comment: on following  your  approach. its  showing  a square  image.

Comment: Same output.. Squared  one.

Comment: Make sure your ion-avatar is placed in ion-item element

Comment: Yes.. Its  placed inside ion-item

Comment: I will get back to the drawing board. -)

Comment: check how i got my answer. If you can replicate this you will perfectly have your solution. ... I added my implementation in ion-card

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
 <ion-avatar item-left (click)="entityProfile(gossip.gossip_about.ID)">
     <img [src]="gossip.gossip_about.img">
 </ion-avatar>
```

SCSS:

```
ion-avatar img {
    width: 50px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: on following your approach. its showing a square image.

Comment: It is working piece of code from my project. May be some other css overriding issue. Inspect image and put above css to element.